# Not able to align the data in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have read the articles related to this but i could not modify mine as per them. I need to align all the data under headings. I have five columns with multiple rows but the data is shown as below.

[image]

I have used only listview in linearlayout as shown

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#F5D8BA">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="item#\nstyle#"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:text="M Wt\nD Wt\nCS Wt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:text="Making\nD Rate\nCS Rate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:text="Margin\nDis %\nDiscount"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GT\nFSP"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />
     //few items goes here
 </LinearLayout>
```

and list view data is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"

        />
     </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"

        />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"

        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Do not use the linear layout for this. You will have to manually set each individually through the text editor, to start on certain distance from the left border. Then you can set maximum character length per line for each textview so they do bot overlap each other

Comment: I did not get you..,what can be done to get proper alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you please look into this related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154208/align-row-data-considering-decimal-point-in-listview

Answer (score 1):

Make width of all TextView(acting as header of columns) of columns equal to the width of all LinearLayout(acting as data column) inside ScrollView as:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#F5D8BA">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="item#\nstyle#"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:text="M Wt\nD Wt\nCS Wt"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:text="Making\nD Rate\nCS Rate"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:text="Margin\nDis %\nDiscount"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GT\nFSP"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:typeface="serif"
    />
```

Then keep the overall width of top LinearLayout and ScrollView same.
This will do the job.

Comment: overall width of both i am not clear..,can you please show me

Comment: mean LinearLayout(top header row) and ScrollView(data columns) should have same width i.e either both "match_parent" or both "wrap_content". you are already doing that.

Comment: Also there is no need to use android:"layout_weight"=1 for LinearLayout as it is the only child of ScrollView(data column). Make height of this LinearLayout "wrap_content".

Comment: its confusing to me..,i got your second point not clear with first..,please edit my code

Comment: just copy paste my code and check the result it should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to relative layout and set all of the to be alligned to the left border of the screen. Now in the design layout you will see under each and every one of the TextViews  - layout:margin. Click the drop down icon and set each and every textviews margin according to where you want it to be (using dp, for example: 50dp, then the next one - 150dp and so on). A slow process, but a secure one.