# Align row data considering decimal point in listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a table format containing columns and multiple rows like

```
 M.wt
  D.wt
  Cs.wt
  12.000
   2.340
   0.997
```

Here M.wt ,D.wt and Cs.wt is the heading column and the values are has shown,i am not able to align the values considering decimal point one below the other,i am getting like

```
12.000
2.566
5.666
```

My layout is like code is like

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif"
                />
     </LinearLayout>
```

How to handle this,it should be handle in layout or java file ?
My screen is actually like so:

[image]

Comment: It's all about alignment. Try using `android:gravity="right"` in your TextViews

Comment: Yes i tried using this..,but still the same.

Comment: Your LinearLayout orientation must be `horizontal`, and its with must be `match_parent`

Comment: but only with this i cannot acheive the decimal points one below the other

Comment: How about using 3 rows?

Comment: Even better, I'd use an ExpandableListView, to only show the rows (children) of the selected item (group).

Comment: no..,because i cannot make any changes to this stuff ..,i just want to acheive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the text that is you are setting to the `TextView` for the 3 decimal points like below

```
  mwt = 0.2f;
  textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id. textView2);
  textView2.setText(String.format("%.3f",mwt));

   dwt = 0.1f;
  textView21 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView21);
  textView2.setText(String.format("%.3f",dwt));
```

Add the gravity property as end and your text view will be

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: I did not get wat it wil do exactly ?..,i can have data like 12344.55666,2445.5555..,just that decimal point should come one below other..,this wil work ?

Comment: If you fix the decimal points to some fixed count it will work.Otherwise you need to programmatically add the spaces based on the highest number of decimal points

Comment: I have fixed three digits after decimal for all m.wt,d.wt and cs.wt..,how can it be handled now?

Comment: We put the gravity as end, so the text will align from end. We are fixing the text to 3 decimal points for all the text views which will give you required output

Comment: But for all the text views in the row should be same gravity. So that it will look gud

Comment: so i can use snippet has it is ?..,mwt=0.2f and dwt=0.1f ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87657/discussion-between-prasad-and-jenil).